# User is not authenticated when the app is running with IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am converting the old dnx beta4 MVC app to the new ASP.NET Core 1.0. I had a simple cookie claim based authentication with custom user lookup (without EF) which was working perfectly.

Luckily, they didn't change much in that area so with small changes here and there I managed to convert it. When running the site with F5 (not IIS) everything seems to work. The `User.Identity.IsAutheticated` property is true, etc.

But when I run the app with IIS the login part seems to work but after that `User.Identity.IsAutheticated` is false.

For publishing my app to the IIS I followed the steps from the documentation (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html)

Any thoughts what might be the problem?

**EDIT**

Just to be clearer, I am using the Identity for authentication. I don't create custom cookie, I use the `CookieAuthencationMiddleware`. I call `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` to authenticate the user, I use implementation of `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` to create the `ClaimsPrincipal` object. I have custom simple `IUserStore` implementation for getting the user (no FE), etc. It perfectly works when running outside IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authentication is probably the problem. If you are writing your own cookie, and reading it, and validating it, then you need to move to an authentication middleware, and then use the `SignInAsync` and `SignoutAsync` on the HttpContext Authentication feature.

I'd suggest switching to using the built in cookie middleware, which you can use quite happily without any dependencies on EF, Identity or anything else.

That is [fully documented](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html) and my [authorization workshop](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop) uses it, so there's plenty of sample code.

Comment: you can have a look on my edit of the question. If code is needed I can provide.

Comment: Hmm that's very weird. Deploying should have no effect, especially as F5 will go through IIS Express normally.

Comment: Now it works and I will accept the answer because it gave me some insights about my issue and I managed to resolve it trying different things.